# Domain unavailable when resuming from sleep

Tags: active-directory, performance, authentication

We have a school library with a bank of computers for students, joined to an active directory domain. I'm investigating an issue with these computers where at some time in the last six to nine months they started having login issues, or network issues when resuming from sleep. When a computer resumes from sleep, it may take as much as four minutes longer for the network to become available than for the computer to show the login screen, resulting in errors that "no domain is available" when students try to log in.

I don't know exactly when this started; it only recently came to my attention. In the meantime, a student would sit down at a computer and if it didn't work just move to the next, or ask a librarian. The librarian would go with the student to watch them try again, and by the time this happens everything is working. Since the librarian never sees a failure, they never reported the problem.

I'm not sure if it's a general network issue (like dhcp taking too long to renew an address) or a domain issue. Prior to the start of the fall term, the computers would always just log in.

I don't know what changed to cause this, because a *lot* has changed over the last six to nine months: the lab updated from Windows XP to Windows 7, we have a new domain controller (including dhcp) running 2008 R2 instead of 2003 (but it's at the 2003 functional level yet). We have a new core layer-3 switch for campus handling routing between the lab vlan and the DC vlan. We have a new switch for the lab itself. In fact, about the only thing that's the same in that area are the old physical cat5e wires.

I've tried changing the "Allow Windows to turn this device off to save power" setting on the network card, but it doesn't help. I've tried immediately logging in as a local administrator, to see if it's a general network issue, but if it is something like a slow dhcp response it's worked itself out by the time the desktop has loaded and I've been able to bring a up a console to check.

From what I can see, *nothing is actually broken* here. The computer will always function normally after just another minute or three. However, the timing of things is unfortunate.

Any ideas on how to resolve or troubleshoot this? Setting them to not go to sleep is not an option right now.

Comment: This was a really tough one to tag, so tag edits are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that if the network is not fully initialized, the user will not be able to logon, unless they have logged on to the computer previously, they have a cached logon, cached logons are enabled, and SID caching has not been disabled.  You may want to confirm if the issue does not occur when logging on with a cached logon.

A network packet capture would help localize the component that is failing.  I.e., is it not getting an IP address right away, has the computer account not yet authenticated.  It will also show what else is occurring, such as group policy processing.  A cross-domain authentication will also add time to the process (either a multi-level domain hierarchy,  explicit trust, or disjoint namespace).

Another useful source of information is in the netlogon.log file when netlogon debugging is enabled.  During startup or resume on a client computer, the network typically is not available right away, and when it does become available, processes such as Group Policy processing typically have an event hook that fires to complete its processing.  That will be surfaced in the netlogon.log file.  This can be enabled with the following registry settings:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters]
"DBFlag"=dword:24401F04
"MaximumLogFileSize"=dword:3200000